# Can an ultrasonic sensor differentiate b/w objects?

Tags: sensors

Can we potentially use an ultrasonic sensor to differentiate between objects based on the reflective capacity of the object?
For example to differentiate between metals and biodegradable wastes.

Comment: yes, but not in the way that you are implying .... it is not the sensor that does the differentiation, it is the computer program that does it

Answer (score 1):

No. No, you can't. All they sense is the "time of flight".

The closest you would come would be to have a sensor which can detect physical properties of the target.  That could be colour, sound absorption, etc.  You'd need something that sends out a "broad spectrum" signal (white light, white noise, etc) and detects the *reflected spectrum* (colour sensor, wide-band microphone) and do spectral analysis of it.  The signal would also have to be fairly tightly focussed to exclude signals from the environment.

All-in-all not something for a little Arduino to consider without lots of extra expensive hardware.

Comment: I guess I could definitely use sound absorption.